# How do I optimize a UICollectionView being populated via a Parse.com query?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I have a Parse.com query of about 150 images, populating a UICollectionView. The images change according to a button that the user taps to segue into the UICollectionView. When tapped, the collection starts to download, and you can see the first three or four images pretty soon.

When you scroll, however, you see the same images that have already been downloaded duplicated and shuffling around, switching places with images that haven't yet downloaded. Eventually they all download, but it takes a LONG time. (Like 90 seconds.) And on top of that, images don't start to load until the user has scrolled to the image's place and waited for it.

I'm a beginner developer so I don't know if this is an obvious fix or something that needs some serious work.  My code is here:

UICollectionView code:

```
var exp = ""

class CollectionCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    images = []
    parseObjects = []
    imageNames = []
    imageExpansions = []

    var downloadCards = PFQuery(className: "Cards")
    downloadCards.whereKey("ExpansionNumber", equalTo:"\(exp)")
    downloadCards.limit = 200
    downloadCards.orderByAscending("Number")
    downloadCards.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) cards.")
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    parseObjects.append(object["Image"] as! PFFile)
                    imageNames.append(object["Number"] as! String)
                    imageExpansions.append(object["ExpansionNumber"] as! String)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } else {
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return parseObjects.count

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell: CardsCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CardsCollectionViewCell
    parseObjects[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{

        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

            cell.cardsImg.image = image

        }   

    }
    //cell.cardLabel.text = imageNames[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
}
```

Button segue/query identifier code here:

```
var images = [UIImage]()
var parseObjects = [PFFile]()
var imageNames = [String]()
var imageExpansions = [String]()

class selectExpansionViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func xy1Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "59"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func xy2Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "60"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func xy3Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "61"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func xy4Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "62"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func xy5Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "63"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func xydcButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "63-2"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func xy6Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "64"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func bw1Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "48"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func bw2Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "49"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func bw3Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "50"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func bw4Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "51"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func bw5Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "52"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func bw6Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "53"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func bw7Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "54"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func bw8Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "55"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func bw9Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "56"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func bw10Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "57"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func bw11Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "58"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func hgss1Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "43"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func hgss2Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "44"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func hgss3Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    exp = "45"
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToCollectionView", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem, is that the UICollectionView reuses the cells.

so, when you use:

```
let cell: CardsCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CardsCollectionViewCell
```

you cant be sure if you are using a new cell or reusing another one.

What you need to do is to set the UIImageView with some placeholder image (may be just a white image). Then parse will update the image when the data is retrieved.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell: CardsCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CardsCollectionViewCell

        cell.cardsImg.image = "your placeholder image while the data are retrived from Parse"

        parseObjects[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{

            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

                cell.cardsImg.image = image

            }   

        }
        //cell.cardLabel.text = imageNames[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

Another thing. You have to refactor that IBActions if the buttons perform almost the same actions. You can connect several Buttons to the same IBAction, and then identify the button clicked with the tag. So, in the storyboard you set a different tag for each button, and then in the function you read that tag with sender.tag. Your code will be better/easier.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this is not what I was asking.